Почему не выводятся товары определенной категории?
У меня проблема следующая — хочу отображать товары определенной категории по клику на соответствующую категорию. Отображаю список товаров через цикл, параметр отправляю, но выдает ошибку «mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in on line 25», хотя без условия цикл отрабатывает верно: Подсказывали уже про WHERE, но я не знаю куда его вставить, если вставить к запросу — то перестает выводиться вообще что-либо. UPD: Массив GET и respItem пустые при попытке посмотреть их через pre и print_r. UPD: С помощью крайнего ответа смог словить подробный текст ошибки:

Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
right syntax to use near 'AND WHERE Product_ID= 1'

Не понял, плюнул, думаю ладно, перепишу на PDO, чтобы не страдать, но нет — установил OS Panel, закинул пути в VS Code, и тут получил ошибку: «php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed». Естественно никаких данных я не менял, они такие же как и в mysqli, в переменных.
UPD: пофиксил, закинув в переменные среды путь. Теперь ошибку выдает уже сам PDO:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown
database

<?php 
include ./header.php';

    ?>
    <?php
    $queryItem = 'SELECT * FROM ProductCustomer';
    
    if(isset($_GET['item'])){
        $queryItem .= " AND Product_ID=$_GET[item]";
    }
    $respItem = mysqli_query($connDB, $queryItem);
    ?>
    while($outputItem = mysqli_fetch_array($respItem)){
              print("<div class='filterItem posPic'>
            <img src='/img/$outputItem[ProductImg]' class='filterPic'>
                               <p class='posPic'>
                               <br>$outputItem[Name]
                              <br>Цена $outputItem[Price] ₽
                             </p>
                

        </div>");
                             };
    ?>


Подозреваю проблема с синтаксисом sql, строка " AND Product_ID=$_GET[item]"; содержит $_GET[item]"; как подстроку, а не передаваемый и подставляемый параметр. Должно быть  " WHERE Product_ID=" . $_GET['item'] ;  если правильно понимаю синтаксис php

выдает ошибку «mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in on line 25» означает, что вместо ожидаемого набора записей предыдущий оператор вернул ошибку. И вот именно текст этой ошибки и надо получить и прочитать.

А как его получить? Массив GET и respItem пустые при попытке посмотреть их через pre и print_r

Посмотрите тут , в аналогичном вопросе приводятся примеры как смотреть и избегать такие ошибки

Это же надо, ни один из доброхотов не увидел бессмысленное сочетание AND WHERE в сообщении об ошибке. Ну и отсутствие WHERE в исходном запросе.

@MrFylypenko извините, но в первом комментарии вы написали полную бессмыслицу. Не нужно комментировать вопросы по языку, синтаксис которого вы не понимаете.

Проблема решена. Ошибка была в имени столбца в базе данных. Как мне объяснили, в базе данных было Product_[пробел]ID, но при этом прямой запрос выполнялся корректно, потому что SQL убрал сам лишние пробелы. А при запросе извне, когда в нем было без пробела, а в БД с пробелом, никто автоматически ничего не делал, а я не видел. Вот так вот. Вывод — смотрите внимательнее, или используйте способы именования без подчеркиваний

"при этом прямой запрос выполнялся корректно, потому что SQL убрал сам лишние пробелы" извините, но это какой-то бред. "SQL" ничего никуда не убирает. И вообще это язык. Кто-то просто глупо посмеялся над вашим невежеством.

При том что проблема была в дурацком AND WHERE Product_ID= 1

Уважаемые участники, не ленитесь нажать кнопочку "Удалить". Этой глупости здесь быть не должно.

Вы чего-то уж сильно волнуетесь из-за моего невежества (что верно). Хотите конкретики — SQL ликвидировал лишний пробел с помощью TRIM автоматически, вот и все. Я неделю пользовался БД и PHP, о каком невежестве вы вообще говорите. Я тоже думал удалить свой вопрос, но на все воля администрации. Лично я считаю, что мой вопрос полезен новичкам, потому что показывает что ошибка может быть не в самом PHP непосредственно.

Давайте лучше я буду волноваться о вашем невежестве, а вы будете читать, что вам пишут. проблема действительно не в самом РНР. А в бессмысленном SQL запросе, который вы написали. И нелепых фантазиях про некий TRIM, который сам по себе взялся неизвестно откуда, и удалил пробел в СЕРЕДИНЕ слова.

Удивлен вашей реакции всего лишь на то, что я написал, что решил свою проблему, про которую здесь же и спрашивал. Утверждать насчет всяких TRIM я не буду — всего лишь передаю объяснения человека, который помог мне найти ошибку при мне же и я видел проверку этого TRIM, хоть и не понял всей сути, но эта проверка помогла человеку найти мою оплошность, вот почему я утверждаю про автоматический TRIM при прямом SQL запросе в PHPMyAdmin, а не просто потому что мне так придумалось. С точки зрения профессионализма мои объяснения некорректны, но примерный контекст таков.

Этот человек - такой же фантазёр-недотёпа. И его объяснения это просто бред. Никакого автоматического вызова TRIM в sql нет. И тем более к именам полей. TRIM может вызываться только при к ЗНАЧЕНИЯМ, при явном вызове в запросе. При этом обрезая пробелы только ПО КРАЯМ, но не внутри строки. Прочтите наконец в документации, если не верите мне, а верите какому-то клоуну-незнайке.

При этом в ошибке, которую вы привели в вопросе, ЧЕРНЫМ ПО БЕЛОМУ ПОКАЗАН КРИВОЙ КОД: условие AND WHERE Product_ID= 1 является бессмысленным.

Мы с вами очень забавные люди — тратим время ни на что. Вы пытаетесь доказать мне то, что мне не нужно уже — ни SQL, ни тем более PHP. Но при этом отвечу, что человек, который мне любезно помог, указав на мою оплошность, тоже сказал что запрос бессмысленный, что я не сразу понял, ведь прямой запрос к базе спокойно выполнялся, а оказалось ошибка в каком-то несчастном пробеле в поле БД. О чем у вас спор я так и не понимаю, проблема решена, ваше мнение я учел, можете более не нервничать. Скорее всего я удалю этот вопрос, ибо и с точки зрения форума он расценен как некорректный

Да, сделайте такое одолжение
